# How to pass down defined Websocket or Peer down other elements in nextJS?

Tags: reactjs, websocket, next.js, peer

As I far as I am given to understand, I cannot define `websocket` or `peer` outside `useEffect`. so I have

```
  pc = new RTCPeerConnection()
  pc.dcm = pc.createDataChannel("channel")
```

inside `useEffect`.
However this way I cannot pass them as `props` to other elements given that they are `async`.
I cannot also use a `react state` to get the updated value passed down because then I won't be able to use them inside `useEffect` since the state will show as its initial value all the time inside `useEffect`.
How to pass down defined `Websocket` or `Peer` down other elements as `props`?

Comment: Have you considered using [React context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) to make them available to multiple components?

Comment: @juliomalves I cannot define it outside useEffect since I will run into reference is undefined.

Comment: You can still access it inside a `useEffect` _and_ use React context to pass it around.

Comment: @juliomalves as you know useEffect can only access the initial value of the state therefore I cannot pass it around if I initialize them as a state ( Which I think it's bad practice anyway ). I only have this issue in Nextjs and not in React in general because outside Nextjs I can define it at root and pass it down as context just like you mentioned.

Comment: I didn't mean to set them as initial state. You'd set them into state inside the `useEffect`.

Comment: @juliomalves I did that but I cannot access the state inside useEffect. here is a sadbox of it : https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-water-51drx and by the way I cannot set the state as dependency because it will rerun useEffect and creates another peer and messes everything up.